# Unable to insert data into MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I've been trying to find a solution, I've found some similar issues but nothing seems to tell exactly how to fix it.

```
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "test") or die("Couldn't connect!");
    $connectdb = mysql_select_db("test") or die("Couldn't connect to database!");
    echo "Connection established to Database.";

    $sql = "INSERT INTO hell (name, age) VALUES ('Josh',17)";

    if ($connect->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
            } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
?>
```

this returns:

> Connection established to Database.
>       Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on resource in
>       C:\xampp\htdocs\php\connect-database.php on line 8

I'm using a slightly changed version from http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Could someone provide me the documentation to fix this or fix the code?

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is ensuring the table exists in your database and you're inserting all values that aren't defaulted or generated by the database (like ID columns). Beyond that it could be your sql doesn't match MySQL's statements.

Comment: I'm sure it does, i created a table using phpmyadmin, i created a database named test and created a table inside of it called hell. I really don't know why it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
if (mysql_query($sql) === TRUE) {
```

instead of

```
if ($connect->query($sql) === TRUE) {
```

And please use mysqli or PDO

Comment: Yeah I will eventually. I just want to get to know SQL and PHP better before I start doing fancy stuff.

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

/* Select queries return a resultset */
if ($result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO hell (name, age) VALUES ('Josh',17)")) {
    printf("New record created successfully\n");

/* free result set */
$result->close();
}
```

PS: It's recommended to use mysqli instead mysql extension.